# Start and Restart async function with setIntervalAsync returns TypeError cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, setinterval, clearinterval

I've been trying to implement a web scraper that will use data pulled from MongoDB to create an array of urls to scrape periodically with puppeteer. I have been trying to get my scraper function to scrape periodically by using setIntervalAsync.

Here is my code right now that throws "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.values..."

**puppeteer.js**

```
 async function scrape(array){      
            // initialize for loop here
            let port = '9052'
            if(localStorage.getItem('scrapeRunning')=='restart'){
                clearIntervalAsync(scrape)
                localStorage.setItem('scrapeRunning') == 'go'
            }else if(localStorage.getItem('scrapeRunning') != 'restart'){
            /// Puppeteer scrapes urls in array here ///
}
```

**server.js**

```
app.post('/submit-form', [
        // Form Validation Here //
    ], (req,res)=>{

        async function submitForm(amazonUrl,desiredPrice,email){
            // Connect to MongoDB and update entry or create new entry
            // with post request data
            createMongo.newConnectToMongo(amazonUrl,desiredPrice,email)
            .then(()=>{
                // Set local variable that will alert scraper to clearIntervalAsync///
                localStorage.setItem('scrapeRunning','restart');
                // before pulling the new updated mongoDB data ...
                return createMongo.pullMongoArray();

            })
            .then((result)=>{
                // and start scraping again with the new data
                puppeteer.scrape(result)
            })
        submitForm(req.body.amazonUrl, req.body.desiredPrice,req.body.email);
     }
}

createMongo.pullMongoArray()
.then((result)=>{
    setIntervalAsync(puppeteer.scrape, 10000, result);
})
```

Currently the scraper starts as expected after the server is started and keeps 10 seconds between when the scrape ends and when it begins again. Once there is a post submit the MongoDB collection gets updated with the post data, the localStorage item is created, but the scrape function goes off the rails and throws the typeError. I am not sure what is going on and have tried multiple ways to fix this (including leaving setIntervalAsync and clearIntervalAsync inside of the post request code block) but have been unsuccessful so far. I am somewhat new to coding, and extremely inexperienced with asynchronous code, so if someone has any experience with this kind of issue and could shed some light on what is happening I would truly appreciate it!

I only think that it has something to do with async as no matter what I have tried it also seems to run the pullMongoArray function  before the newConnectToMongo function is complete.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of searching around I think I may have found a workable solution.  I've completely eliminated the use of localStorage and removed the if and else if statements from within the scrape function. I have also make a global timer variable and added control functions to this file.

**puppeteer.js**

```
let timer;

function start(result){
    timer = setIntervalAsync(scrape,4000, result)
}

function stop(){
    clearIntervalAsync(timer)
}


async function scrape(array){       
        // initialize for loop here
        let port = '9052'
        // Puppeteer scrapes urls from array here //
}
```

I've altered my server code a little bit so at the server start it gets the results from MongoDB and uses that in the scraper start function. A post request also calls the stop function before updating MongoDB, pulling a new result from MongoDB, and then recalling the start scraper function.

**server.js**

```
createMongo.pullMongoArray()
.then((result)=>{
    puppeteer.start(result);
})

app.post('/submit-form', [
        // Form Validation In Here //
    ], (req,res)=>{

        async function submitForm(amazonUrl,desiredPrice,email){
            // Stop the current instance of the scrape function
            puppeteer.stop();
            // Connect to MongoDB and update entry or create new entry
            // with post request data
            createMongo.newConnectToMongo(amazonUrl,desiredPrice,email)
            .then(()=>{
                // before pulling the new updated mongoDB data ...
                console.log('Pulling New Array');
                return createMongo.pullMongoArray();
            })
            .then((result)=>{
                // and restarting the repeating scrape function
                puppeteer.start(result);
            })
      }
})
```